# How to pass arguments of outer function into inner function implicitly?

Tags: function-construction, pattern-matching, argument-patterns, downvalues

Consider the following setup:

```
ClearAll[f,g];

g[string_]:=TemplateApply[
    StringTemplate@string,
    <|"product"->Symbol["product"]|>
];

f[product_]:=g["This is a test `product` for package!"];
```

My actual `g` function is more general and finds the template slots in the string and replaces slot `SlotName` by `Symbol["SlotName"]`. But the issue I am facing is the arguments are provided via `DownValues` and so are not getting detected. How do I make it work?

```
f["PROD"]
```

produces:

> "This is a test product for package!"

But I want:

> "This is a test PROD for package!"

Is there a construct `SendArguments` that can pass `DownValue` patterns further down?

```
g[string_,ReceiveArguments[]]:=TemplateApply[
    StringTemplate@string,
    <|"product"->product|>
];

f[product_]:=g["This is a test `product` for package!",SendArguments[]];
```

How to do this? Wolfram is a symbolic language so there must be a way to achieve this?

Comment: Are you expecting `Symbol["SlotName"]` to somehow create a "local" symbol and have it be bound to an argument passed in to `g`?

Answer (score 1):

I feel like I must be missing something, because it sounds like you just want a straightforward passing of arguments:

```
g[string_, productReplacement_] := 
  TemplateApply[StringTemplate@string, <|"product" -> productReplacement|>];
f[product_] := g["This is a test `product` for package!", product];

f["PROD"]
(* "This is a test PROD for package!" *)
```

Answer (score 0):

I really think this is a bad idea, but if you truly want "implicit", you may need to let your special symbols live "outside" your functions. You could do this by setting up a special context, or you could go ahead and use the Global context, but in that case you might want to Protect them.

```
(* Using Global context, but trying to be safe *)
Protect[product];
g[string_] := TemplateApply[StringTemplate@string, <|"product" -> product|>];
f[productReplacement_] := 
  Block[
    {product = productReplacement}, 
    g["This is a test `product` for package!"]];

f["PROD"]
(* "This is a test PROD for package!" *)


(* Using a "private" context *)
ClearAll[f, g];
g[string_] := TemplateApply[StringTemplate@string, <|"product" -> Arguments`product|>];
f[productReplacement_] := 
  Block[
    {Arguments`product = productReplacement}, 
    g["This is a test `product` for package!"]];

(* Alternative, but same basic idea *)
ClearAll[f, g];

g[string_] := TemplateApply[StringTemplate@string, <|"product" -> Arguments`product|>];
f[productReplacement_] := 
  (Arguments`product = productReplacement; g["This is a test `product` for package!"]);
```